# Locate a link and copy it without clicking in protractor

Tags: protractor

I need to locate a link on the page and copy it or store it as a string without clicking it in a protractor test. I can locate the element but am not sure how to store it as a string. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all the selenium-specific Protractor methods [return promises](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#promises-and-the-control-flow).

You will have to store the link as a "promise" and resolve once the value is needed:

```
var link = $("#mylink_id").getAttribute("href");

link.then(function (actualLinkAsString) {
    // do something with actualLinkAsString  
});
```

Comment: I'm having issues with this again. In my page object file, the link is located by css. What I need to do is click this link, and then store the url so that I can access it again later.
Any recommendations on how to do sp?

Comment: @Kelsey I think you can resolve the `browser.getCurrentUrl()` promise once you click the link. But, please do ask a separate question if you need further help. This way we are not going to pollute comments here and more people may potentially help you if it's a separate topic. Thanks for understanding.